# Microsoft Access SQL query for an attribute that does not exist

Tags: ms-access

I have the query below however am unsure how I return values that do not have the flag attribute. I tried `type.Property <> 'Flag'` however that returns no results even though there are records that don't have the flag attribute

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE, o.name as Name
FROM ((t_object as o
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as location
         ON o.Object_ID = location.Object_ID)
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type 
         ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID)
WHERE location.Property = 'Location' 
  AND location.Value = 'Queens'
  AND type.Property = 'Flag'
  ORDER BY o.name ASC
```

Comment: You may get rows with type.Property IS NULL if the column allows nulls.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem - It tried that but that didn't work either

Comment: Start by testing the part after WHERE by itself. See what values do you get. Execlude nulls by specifying Select * from ... Where (Type.Property is not null and type.Property='Flag') and location.Value='Queens' and location.Property = 'Location'

Comment: @Emmad Kareem - The suggestion you posted does not work. It only returns results that have the flag attribute

Comment: If you don't want the value 'flag' then you do Where (Type.Property is not null and type.Property <> 'Flag') and location.Value='Queens' and location.Property = 'Location'.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem - That does not work either. I get no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear about exactly what you want.  This should give you rows where `type.Property` is anything other than `'Flag'`, including Nulls.

```sql
AND Nz(type.Property, '') <> 'Flag'
```

If you will be running the query from outside an Access application session, use `IIf` instead of `Nz`.

```sql
AND IIf(type.Property Is Null, '', type.Property) <> 'Flag'
```

If you want only those rows where `type.Property` is Null ...

```sql
AND type.Property Is Null
```

Comment: I tried all those queries and they return results that still have the flag attribute with the exception of the last query which returns no value. What I want are elements that have no flag attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type.Property IS NULL` if the value needs to be tested for null. There is no equality test for null in SQL.

Comment: Thanks although i get the error `Syntax error (operator missing)

Comment: the `[NOT]` indicates that the token is optional. I was not clear whether you needed null values, or wanted the ones without. Either remove the entire token, or just the enclosing '[]' brackets. If the field is defined as not allowing nulls, the empty fields may be empty strings. Use either `type.Property = ''` or `type.Property = '     '`, depending on whether the field is padded with spaces or not.

Comment: `type.Property IS NOT NULL` worked however it returns results with the flag attribute. I only want those without the flag attribute